# jquery .Change and image show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").hide();

    var img = $('<img class="imgtick">'); 
    img.attr('src', "../Image/tick.png");
    img.appendTo('.test');


    $(".text1").change(function() {
        $(".test").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<label>Address:</label>
<input type="text" class="text1" name="address" value="" placeholder="Address"> 
<span class="test"></span><br>

<label>Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" class="text1"  name="contact" value="" placeholder="Contact" maxlength="8">
<span class="test"></span><br>

<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" class="text1" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
<span class="test"></span><br>
```

i gave a span class "test" and create img tag with class "imgtick" and append to class "test" and hide all the image.

but i want only 1 image to appear when the textbox is onchange.
is it possible to do with class or do i have to define a id for each textbox in order to make the image appear individually when onchange?

Comment: Have you looked into the DOM and selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the next span element using jQuery [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".text1").change(function() {
    $(this).next("span").show();
});
```

Or if you want to use the class use

```
$(this).next(".test").show();
```

jQuery `next()` gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3zywfoun/1/) is a working example

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working for me. i'll read more on the .next jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your change function should be :

`$(".text1").change(function() {
   $(this).next(".test").show();
});`